# Typescript library without tsd file. Cannot instantiate class

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript with angular and want to use the moltin js Sdk. For this Sdk no tsd file exists.

```
var moltin = new Moltin({publicId: 'xxx'});
```

When calling the Moltin class like tihs I get the error:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Moltin'
```

So what do I have to do to make this work? I included the library in my index file so it should work, and does in normal javascript.
Would be happy if I don't have to create a tsd file on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a definition file, you can write an ambient definition:

```
declare var Moltin: any;
```

This will mean you can use the `Moltin` variable in any way you'd like... similar to the wild west of regular JavaScript. To prevent using `Moltin` incorrectly, I would recommend writing a definition with some type information to create restriction that at least meets its use in your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that made it work. I will write the definitions as soon as  I checked out if the api works for us.